# Calcular cuantos días faltan con este método

Tags: java, android

Tengo un método para que calcule cuantos años tiene una persona (teniendo en cuenta el día y mes).
Quiero que con este mismo método poder calcular cuantos días restan desde el día que estamos hasta esa fecha que he seleccionado

Es decir, si en mi `DatePickerDialog` selecciono

25/02/2017

mi `editTextEdad` quede así

6

Yo calculo la edad de la siguiente manera, quiero poder utilizar este mismo método, que opino, que no habría problemas.

`CalcuEdad`

```
public class CalcuEdad {
    private int startYear;
    private int startMonth;
    private int startDay;
    private int endYear;
    private int endMonth;
    private int endDay;
    private int resYear;
    private int resMonth;
    private int resDay;
    private Calendar end;
    public String getCurrentDate()
    {
        end=Calendar.getInstance();
        endYear=end.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        endMonth=end.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        endMonth++;
        endDay=end.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        return endDay+":"+endMonth+":"+endYear;
    }
    public void setDateOfBirth(int sYear, int sMonth, int sDay)
    {
        startYear=sYear;
        startMonth=sMonth;
        startMonth++;
        startDay=sDay;

    }
    public void calcualteYear()
    {
        resYear=endYear-startYear;

    }

    public void calcualteMonth()
    {
        if(endMonth>=startMonth)
        {
            resMonth= endMonth-startMonth;
        }
        else
        {
            resMonth=endMonth-startMonth;
            resMonth=12+resMonth;
            resYear--;
        }

    }
    public void  calcualteDay()
    {

        if(endDay>=startDay)
        {
            resDay= endDay-startDay;
        }
        else
        {
            resDay=endDay-startDay;
            resDay=30+resDay;
            if(resMonth==0)
            {
                resMonth=11;
                resYear--;
            }
            else
            {
                resMonth--;
            }

        }
    }

    public String getResult()
    {
        return resDay+":"+resMonth+":"+resYear;
    }

}
```

Mi `clase`

```
    private static DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener selectorFecha;
    private int dia, mes, ano, hora, minutos;
    private CalcuEdad age = null;
    private TextView calculaedad1;
    TextView editTextEdad;

....

        age = new CalcuEdad();
        calculaedad1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.calcuedad1);
        calculaedad1.setText(age.getCurrentDate());
        editTextEdad = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextEdad);

....

  final Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance();
        dia = calendario.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        mes = calendario.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        ano = calendario.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        hora = calendario.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        minutos = calendario.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        mostrarFecha();
        selectorFecha = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

                age.setDateOfBirth(ano, mes, dia);
                calculateAge();
                mostrarFecha();

            }
        };

    }

 private void calculateAge() {
        age.calcualteYear();
        age.calcualteMonth();
        age.calcualteDay();
        String[] dayMonthYear = age.getResult().split(":");
        String year = dayMonthYear[2];
        editTextEdad.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.edad_actual) + " " + year + " " + (getResources().getString(R.string.age)));
    }
```

**EDITO3:** @TwoDent

`clase` con los nuevos cambios:

```
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String fechDate;
    TextView abc;
    private int dias, mes, ano;
    private static final int TIPO_DIALOGO = 0;
    private static DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener selectorFecha;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        abc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.abc);

        final Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance();
        dias = calendario.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        mes = calendario.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        ano = calendario.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        selectorFecha = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfYear) {
                dias = dayOfYear;
                mes = month;
                ano = year;
                fechDate = dias + "/" + (mes+1) + "/" + ano;
                mostrarFecha();
            }
        };
    }

        @Override
        protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
            switch (id) {
                case 0:
                    return new DatePickerDialog(this, selectorFecha, ano, mes, dias);
            }
            return null;
        }

    public void mostrarCalendario(View control) {
        showDialog(TIPO_DIALOGO);
    }

    public void mostrarFecha() {
        abc.setText(diasRestantes(convertToDate(fechDate)))
        ;}

    // no puede ser estatica porque no son compatible con abc.setText...

    private Date convertToDate(String fecha){
        SimpleDateFormat Formateo = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Date aux;
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        try{
            aux = calendar.getTime();
            Date tipoDate = Formateo.parse(fecha);
            if(tipoDate.before(aux) && !Formateo.format(aux).equals(Formateo.format(tipoDate)))
                abc.setText("ERROR: Esta fecha es menor que la actual.");
            else
                return tipoDate;
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main2Activity.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }

    // no puede ser estatica porque no son compatible con abc.setText...

    public void main(String[]args){
        int dia = 18, mes = 02, ano = 2017;
        String fecha = dia + "/" + mes + "/" + ano;
        abc.setText("Este es el día de hoy" + fecha);
        if(convertToDate(fecha) == null)
            abc.setText("Esta fecha es invalida");
        else
            abc.setText("Dias restantes a la fecha asignada:" + diasRestantes(convertToDate(fecha)));
    }

    private static String diasRestantes(Date fecha){
        DateFormat dd = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        int dias = 0; boolean activo = false;
        Calendar calendar; Date aux;
        do{
            calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, dias);
            aux = calendar.getTime();
            if(dd.format(aux).equals(dd.format(fecha)))
                activo = true;
            else
                dias++;
        }while(activo != true);
        if(dias==0)
            return "El dia es hoy!!! no falta ningun dia!";
        else
            return "Dias restantes: " + dias;

    }
}
```

*LOGCAT*

> 02-20 00:00:00.019 8067-8067/nueva.pruebaedittext E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main     Process: nueva.pruebaedittext, PID: 8067
>     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'long java.util.Date.getTime()' on a null object reference        at
>   java.util.Calendar.setTime(Calendar.java:1089)        at
>   java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:936)      at
>   java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:929)      at
>   java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:337)      at
>   nueva.pruebaedittext.Main2Activity.diasRestantes(Main2Activity.java:105)
>         at
>   nueva.pruebaedittext.Main2Activity.mostrarFecha(Main2Activity.java:63)
>         at
>   nueva.pruebaedittext.Main2Activity$1.onDateSet(Main2Activity.java:44)
>         at android.app.DatePickerDialog.onClick(DatePickerDialog.java:171)
>         at
>   com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
>         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)         at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6176)         at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)        at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)

Comment: Ok... leyendo tu codigo nuevo, veo que al tu registrar el dia, mes y año (int los 3) en el metodo sobreescrito, seguidamente usas "mostrarFecha()"... creo que por eso te devuelve el mismo dia que marcaste como edad

Comment: La funcion solamente recibe como parametro datos del tipo Date. Es por eso que recibes tal error... ademas no has declarado tal variable "date"

Comment: Podrías actualizar tu pregunta guiándome de como podría arreglar mi código? Muchas gracias @TwoDent

Comment: Dejame asimilar bien todo, y ya te doy una solucion en breve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mira, he preparado un pequeño programa como ejemplo para que tengas una idea de mas o menos como lo puedes conseguir. El programa calcula cuantos dias faltan para tu cumpleaños:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*Aqui esta la fecha de ejemplo que has dado para esta pregunta.*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*Bueno... de quien sera este cumpleaños?... :)*

Ahora vamos al rollo...

```
package Edad;

import com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser;
import com.toedter.calendar.JTextFieldDateEditor;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class Main extends JFrame{
    private JDateChooser date;
    private JLabel Dias;
    private Calendar c;
    private Font font;
    public Main(){
        super("¿Cuantos dias faltan?");
        setSize(400,300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);        
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.decode("#F7F2E0"));
        setLayout(new MigLayout());
        font = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF,Font.ITALIC,18);
        c = Calendar.getInstance();
        date = new JDateChooser(c.getTime());
        date.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 20));
        ((JTextFieldDateEditor)date.getDateEditor()).setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        ((JTextFieldDateEditor)date.getDateEditor()).setEditable(false);
        date.getDateEditor().addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent pce) {
                Dias.setText("Para tu cumpleaños faltan: " + diasRestantes(date.getDate()) + " dias!!!");
            }
        });
        add(date,"dock north");
        add(new JLabel(),"wrap 40");
        Dias = new JLabel("Aqui mencionare los dias restantes!",SwingConstants.CENTER);
        Dias.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,280));
        Dias.setFont(font);
        add(Dias,"dock south");
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[]args){
        Main obj = new Main();     
    }  

    private int diasRestantes(Date fecha){        
    DateFormat dd = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");       
    int dias = 0; boolean activo = false;
    Calendar calendar; Date aux;
    do{       
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();           
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, dias);
        aux = calendar.getTime();
        if(dd.format(aux).equals(dd.format(fecha)))
            activo = true; 
        else
            dias++;
    }while(activo != true);
    return dias; 
}
}
```

Ignorando el constructor y demas, aqui el que hace la "magia"  es el señor ***diasRestantes***, el cual es una funcion que devuelve los dias restantes para equis fecha que le pases como parametro:

```
private int diasRestantes(Date fecha){        
    DateFormat dd = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");       
    int dias = 0; boolean activo = false;
    Calendar calendar; Date aux;
    do{       
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();           
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, dias);
        aux = calendar.getTime();
        if(dd.format(aux).equals(dd.format(fecha)))
            activo = true; 
        else
            dias++;
    }while(activo != true);
    return dias; 
}
```

Y pienso que con esto te puedo inyectar una buena idea para la necesidad de tu programa!

***Actualizacion!!***

Muy bien, luego de un par de pruebas y experimentos, he escrito el siguiente codigo el cual probaremos enseguida... pero primero veamos un detalle importante en tu codigo:

Pude notar que en un trozo de tu codigo tomabas el dia, el mes y el año como tipos enteros... como se puede apreciar:

```
 selectorFecha = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfYear) {
                dias = dayOfYear;
                mes = month;
                ano = year;
                mostrarFecha();
            }
        };
```

Vamos a sacarle provecho a esta situacion... primero, escribi la siguiente funcion llamada **convertToDate**, que nos permite recibir una cadena **String** como parametro y devolver dicha cadena String como tipo ***Date***:

```
private static Date convertToDate(String fecha){
    SimpleDateFormat Formateo = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    try{           
        Date tipoDate = Formateo.parse(fecha);
        return tipoDate;
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Esto se debe realizar dentro de un *Try Catch*. Lo que haremos a continuacion es crear una variable String auxiliar dentro del metodo main, que concatene el dia, el mes y por ultimo el año, separado por "/".

Ahora, hagamos pruebas en el metodo **Main** de la clase. Utilizemos las mismas fechas que usamos en el programa anterior que te mostre primeramente:

*02/25/2017*

```
public static void main(String[]args){
    int dia = 25, mes = 02, ano = 2017;
    String fecha = dia + "/" + mes + "/" + ano;
    System.out.println("Este es el dia de hoy: " + fecha);
    System.out.println("Ahora si esta en el tipo Date la fecha: " + convertToDate(fecha));
    System.out.println("Dias restantes a la fecha asignada: " + diasRestantes(convertToDate(fecha)));
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*16/10/2017*

```
 public static void main(String[]args){
    int dia = 16, mes = 10, ano = 2017;
    String fecha = dia + "/" + mes + "/" + ano;
    System.out.println("Este es el dia de hoy: " + fecha);
    System.out.println("Ahora si esta en el tipo Date la fecha: " + convertToDate(fecha));
    System.out.println("Dias restantes a la fecha asignada: " + diasRestantes(convertToDate(fecha)));
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podemos notar, la conversion se esta haciendo correctamente, ya que nuestra funcion **diasRestantes** no nos arroja ningun error de tipo.

***¿Como podrias implementar todo esto en tu codigo?***

1) Declara un atributo mas de clase, que sea **String**.

```
 public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView abc;
    private int dias, mes, ano;
    private String fechDate; //<-------- Variable que concatenara enteros
    private static final int TIPO_DIALOGO = 0;
    private static DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener selectorFecha;
```

2) Pega el codigo de la funcion que convierte cadenas String a Date (**convertToDate**) en tu clase.

3) Al momento de recoger el dia, mes y año, usa la variable de clase String creada para concatenar todo.

```
selectorFecha = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfYear) {
                dias = dayOfYear;
                mes = month;
                ano = year;
                fechDate = dias + "/" + mes + "/" + ano
                mostrarFecha();
            }
        };
```

4) Por ultimo, modificamos ese metodo **mostrarFecha()**.

```
 public void mostrarFecha() {       
     abc.setText("Faltan" + diasRestantes(convertToDate(fechDate))+ " dias")
  ;}
```

Ya con eso deberia bastar...

***Si el usuario ingresa una fecha inferior a la actual***

Se podria hacer algo asi por ejemplo:

```
 private static Date convertToDate(String fecha){
    SimpleDateFormat Formateo = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date aux;
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();    
    try{          
        aux = calendar.getTime();
        Date tipoDate = Formateo.parse(fecha);
        if(tipoDate.before(aux) && !Formateo.format(aux).equals(Formateo.format(tipoDate)))
            System.out.println("ERROR: Esta fecha es menor que la actual.");
        else    
            return tipoDate;
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return null;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Metodo Main

```
public static void main(String[]args){
    int dia = 18, mes = 02, ano = 2017;
    String fecha = dia + "/" + mes + "/" + ano;
    System.out.println("Este es el dia de hoy: " + fecha);
    if(convertToDate(fecha) == null)
        System.out.println("Esta fecha es invalida, intenta de nuevo.");
    else
        System.out.println("Dias restantes a la fecha asignada: " + diasRestantes(convertToDate(fecha)));
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***Mandar la cadena notificando si la fecha actual es igual a la enviada***

Solamente tendria que agregar condiciones en el main, como ver si la cantidad de dias es igual a 0.

```
public static void main(String[]args){
    int dia = 19, mes = 02, ano = 2017;
    String fecha = dia + "/" + mes + "/" + ano;
    System.out.println("Este es el dia de hoy: " + fecha);
    if(convertToDate(fecha) == null){
        System.out.println("Esta fecha es invalida, intenta de nuevo.");
    }else{
        if(diasRestantes(convertToDate(fecha)) == 0)
            System.out.println("El dia es hoy!!! no falta ningun dia!");
        else
            System.out.println("Dias restantes a la fecha asignada: " + diasRestantes(convertToDate(fecha)));
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas ideas tienes ahora.. :)

***Actualizacion 3***

Version alternativa de la funcion *diasRestantes* que devuelve una cadena **String**:

```
 private static String diasRestantes(Date fecha){        
    DateFormat dd = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");       
    int dias = 0; boolean activo = false;
    Calendar calendar; Date aux;
    do{       
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();           
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, dias);
        aux = calendar.getTime();
        if(dd.format(aux).equals(dd.format(fecha)))
            activo = true; 
        else
            dias++;
    }while(activo != true);
    if(dias==0)
        return "El dia es hoy!!! no falta ningun dia!";
    else
        return "Dias restantes: " + dias;

}
```

***Actualizacion 4***

Volvamos a observar la funcion

```
SimpleDateFormat Formateo = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date aux;
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();    
    try{          
        aux = calendar.getTime();
        Date tipoDate = Formateo.parse(fecha);
        if(tipoDate.before(aux) && !Formateo.format(aux).equals(Formateo.format(tipoDate))) //Condicion que se cumple
            System.out.println("ERROR: Esta fecha es menor que la actual.");
        else    
            return tipoDate;
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return null;
    }
    return null;
```

Lo que ocurre, es que al pasarle una fecha que es menor a la actual, la funcion reclama que la fecha es menor y como consecuencia, devuelve un valor **Nulo**. Este detalle se puede resolver facilmente con una condicion if:

```
if(convertToDate(fecha) != null)
    System.out.println(diasRestantes(convertToDate(fecha)));
```

En tu caso...

```
  public void mostrarFecha() {
    if(convertToDate(fechDate) != null)
    abc.setText(diasRestantes(convertToDate(fechDate)))
    ;}
```

El metodo main que tienes ahi, solamente yo lo cree para demostrarte como funciona, no necesariamente tienes que tenerlo tu ahi:

```
public void main(String[]args){
    int dia = 18, mes = 02, ano = 2017;
    String fecha = dia + "/" + mes + "/" + ano;
    abc.setText("Este es el día de hoy" + fecha);
    if(convertToDate(fecha) == null)
        abc.setText("Esta fecha es invalida");
    else
        abc.setText("Dias restantes a la fecha asignada:" + diasRestantes(convertToDate(fecha)));
}
```

Puedes cambiar la funcion y que en vez de arrojar un *Sistem.out*, se imprima donde tu desees (abc):

```
private static Date convertToDate(String fecha){
    SimpleDateFormat Formateo = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date aux;
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();    
    try{          
        aux = calendar.getTime();
        Date tipoDate = Formateo.parse(fecha);
        if(tipoDate.before(aux) && !Formateo.format(aux).equals(Formateo.format(tipoDate)))
            abc.setText("Esta fecha es invalida");
        else    
            return tipoDate;
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return null;
    }
    return null;
}
```

o bien, agregar un else en el metodo *mostrarFecha*

```
public void mostrarFecha() {
    if(convertToDate(fechDate) != null){
      abc.setText(diasRestantes(convertToDate(fechDate)))
    }else{
      abc.setText("Esta fecha es invalida");
    }
    ;}
```

Comment: Claro que puedes. Tendrias que cambiar el tipo devuelto de la funcion "diasRestantes" por el tipo String. En cuanto a lo otro del error, puedes manejar facilmente esto utilizando la funcion ".before". Ahi te dare un ejemplo de Guia

Comment: A la funcion diasRestantes, agregale "static". Ejemplo: public static int diasRestantes() . . . @UserNameYo

Comment: Ok empezando que tu estas haciendo una aplicacion para android, yo estoy corriendo el codigo desde un IDE en la Computadora, no necesariamente tenias que añadir el metodo main textual. Solamente te daba ideas de como podrias lograr lo que querias. Hay muchisimas formas existentes para arrojar eso que quieres cuando la fecha enviada es igual al dia actual.

Comment: Ojo con eso de la fecha, puede ser que en tu maquina este configurada la hora de forma distinta a la mia. Como puedes ver en todas las capturas hechas, se partia desde la fecha actual el conteo (hoy) @UserNameYo

Comment: Ya está arreglado lo del calendario que me salia mal, estaba utilizando `DAY_OF_YEAR` y no `DAY_OF_MONTH`, también he solucionado el problema del mes que no lo reconocía bien, faltaba el +1 en `(mes+1)` podrías echarme una mano con el tema de que se cierra al seleccionar un día anterior? ya que quiero usar el mismo `TimePickerDialog` para calcular la edad, y si no puedo seleccionar días anteriores, pues no me funcionaría @TwoDent

Comment: Estas segura que no te esta funcionando la version nueva de "convertToDate"? (Actualizacion 2)... @UserNameYo

Comment: Obviamente no vas a usar System.out.println por estar creando una app de android eh?, ahi puedes imprimir el mensaje de error en cualquier otra parte claro... (por ejemplo.. una etiqueta.. o Label..)

Comment: He vuelto a actualizar la pregunta con el código actualizado, ya funciona sin problemas cuando estoy en el día de hoy, pero sigue sin funcionar cuando marco un día anterior, se sigue cerrando, `logcat` me marca "  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long java.util.Date.getTime()' on a null object reference" he cambiado `System.ouit.println` por `abc.setText("Esta fecha es invalida");` también he cambiado `private Date convertToDate(String fecha)` y `public void main(String[]args)` ya que no pueden ser `static` al usar `setText`

Comment: Ok, aqui hay fallos mios, Voy a actualizar las funciones con los arreglos correspondientes @UserNameYo

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53918/discussion-between-twodent-and-usernameyo).

Comment: Solucionado! Gracias @TwoDent

Comment: @UserNameYo te encuentras? http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53923/proyecto-usernameyo